# CPU performance decreases with AC power

Tags: 12.04, performance, cpu

I am doing CPU-intensive work on my Thinkpad X220 laptop and I find the performance bad. Interestingly, the CPU becomes more powerful if I disconnect the AC power and run only on battery! It does slow down after a while though, probably because the CPU gets too hot.

Still I find the CPU too slow and I need to increase its performance somehow. I installed jupiter manager, but setting cpu to maximum performance from it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I bought an extra power supply for my laptop (for my bag) Turns out that some 'replacement' power supplies have a lower max watage and the computer senses that and then throttles the CPU. In my case, on battery=full speed, original adapter=full speed, new adapter=throttled.